# How to stop users from registering ane existing name laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

How can I stop users from registering an existing name in the database? I would like to stop this from happening and I am using Laravel 5.5 
for example: there is a user callled John Doe and then a new user registers the same name and i would want to stop this from happening.
This is my register controller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255|alpha|',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You just put an unique validation to the users' name column:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255|alpha|unique:users',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
]);
```

PS: The question is, why would you do that? There are a lot of persons having the same name.

Comment: By 'name' I'm assuming he means 'username'?

Comment: then my question is useless